# How to package a python3K application to an executable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, package

I would like to deliver the application to my client, who don't have any computer knowledge, therefore, I don't wanna to let him/her to use terminal to execute my script. How can I make a single package, and let the user double click and execute?? Is there any way to do so??
Moreover, is this possible to package the python runtime to the application? Because the client may not wanna to install python.... I just wanna him/her running something like a .exe written from C, just double click and execute it. Any tools to do so?? Thanks.

Please recommend for Windows & Mac OS X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Py2Exe for Windows:

http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/FAQ

And a brief Google leads me to Py2App for OS X:

http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html

Comment: `py2exe` doesn't support Pthon 3.x, and IIRC `py2app` doesn't either.